# How do I solve for the real roots of $P (x)=1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^4}{4} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the real zeroes of the polynomial

$P (x)=1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^4}{4} $

So I've computed the derivative as is hinted in my textbook:

$P'(x)=-1+x-3x^2 + 4x^3$

Although, I'm not sure if I can solve for the roots of this polynomial without the help of a computer.

Comment: The derivative is wrong. Hint: the goal is not to compute the roots.

Comment: $P'(x) = -1+x-x^2+x^3=(-1+x)+x^2(-1+x)=(x-1)(x^2+1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$P'(x)=-1+x-x^2+x^3=(x-1)(x^2+1)$$

Thus the derivative has only one real root, and $P$ is decreasing on $]-\infty,1]$, and increasing on $[1,+\infty[$.

And $P(1)=1/2-1/3+1/4=1/6+1/4>0$.

How many real roots does $P$ have?

Comment: Elegant solution (+1)

Answer (score 2):

A little algebraic finagling produces

$$36P(x)=9x^4-12x^3+18x^2-36x+36=(3x^2-2x+1)^2+8(x-2)^2+3$$

which shows that $P(x)\gt0$ for all $x$.